Не отправляются уведомления при запуске программы с .exe файла
Приложение использует plyer и schedule для отправки уведомления в Центр уведомлений Windows в заданное время (schedule запускается из второго потока).
При запуске из PyCharm все работает как надо, однако после преобразования файла в .exe уведомление не отправляются, хотя второй поток при этом работает, и функция job запускается в нужное время.
Вот этот код:
    def pars_files(self):
        check = os.listdir(f'notes')
        thread3 = ()

    if self.date in check:

        path = os.path.join('notes', f'{self.date}')
        check2 = os.listdir(path)

        for i in range(24):

            if i == len(check2):
                break
            path2 = os.path.join(path, f'{check2[i]}')

            with open(os.path.join(path2, 'time'), 'r') as f:
                self.spec_time = f.read()

            with open(os.path.join(path2, 'name'), 'r') as f:
                self.name = f.read()

            with open(os.path.join(path2, 'description'), 'r') as f:
                self.description = f.read()

            thr = Thread(target=self.thread, daemon=True)
            thr.start()
    else:
        return

def thread(self):

    def job():
        plyer.notification.notify(message=self.description, title=self.name)


    schedule.every().day.at(self.spec_time).do(job)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


Если в оболочке работает, а в автономной сборке нет, даже и гадать нечего - в автономной сборке не хватает тех компонентов, которые доступны для оболочки. В данном условии есть всё, что угодно, кроме главного - структуры импорта модулей и подробного описания процедуры сборки автонома. Что такое plyer и schedule, чьё оно и откуда берётся, остаётся только гадать.

Plyer - библиотека для доступа к аппаратным функциям различных платформ, в данном случае используется для отправки уведомлений. Schedule - библиотека для планирования задач на нужное время(здесь используется для выполнения функции отправки уведомления).  Для сборки файла в .exe используется Auto PY to exe (https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/) . Не уверен, что вы имеете в виду под структурой импорта модулей, предположу что это: import schedule import plyer  @FoxFox

Параметры Auto PY to exe: https://i.sstatic.net/KcWi58Gy.png

С этим не работаю. Работаю с pyinstaller. Он простой, понятный, а главное безотказный. У меня не было проблем и не бывает в виде разницы работы в оболочке и в автономном режиме. Более того, я работаю непосредственно с файлами .py в операционной системе - пишу в Notepad и тут же тестирую. Если они запускаются и работают нормально, значит автоном, собранный из них, тоже работает. Извините, помочь более не смогу.
Не лишним будет напомнить о том, что и Питон, и все версии модулей, и этот Ваш сборщик должны быть обновлены до актуальных версий, если хотите что-то понять.
